# Everything on my pc requires administrative password

Tags: windows-8.1

If I open command prompt it asks for administrator password which I do not know. My every app or tool has been set on administrative password suddenly.If I go to computer management there also it asks for password.

Help me please. I have tried to find the solution, I know my pin though

Comment: Aren't you using Administrative User Account or there is another Admin account on your Machine.

Comment: Sounds like your account recently lost most or all of its permissions (for example, got removed from the Users group). Have you done anything recently that could have caused something like that? Some possibilities: a big Windows upgrade, joining or leaving a domain, mucking with account settings manually, mucking with Group Policy or similar, or giving somebody else access to your computer.

Comment: i downloaded and ran bitdefender adware cleaner .After scanning and removing Adware ...i found everything set on password.....and the bitdefender adware cleaner was also gone

Comment: murtaza ...when i bought this laptop i set it on pin which i know now also...everything i used  required administrator permission thenn also but now it along with its permission it asks for password too,which i do not know...i think  one of the workers of the shop who was supposed to install necessary softwares set the password

Answer (score -1):

I guess u r using a user account which has been set limits y the computer administrator's account. You will need to login into admin account and set off the limits to ur user account or create new admin account. And if u cant access that, i am afraid u will have to install new windows. And if u do not  want that find out admin accounts username and hack it open if its windows 7.

Comment: Ash,i am going to a Tech shop now,very thanks for ur advice though